# Histogram with a jittery rug

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

The following script

```
library(ggplot2)
dat<-rnorm(80)
dat<-data.frame(dat)
p<-ggplot(dat, aes(x=dat))+geom_histogram()
p<-p+geom_rug(sides="b", colour="blue")
p
```

makes this pretty picture:

[image: Histogram with a rug]

But many of those blue lines overlap. I'd like to add some jitter! I've tried using:

```
p<-p+geom_rug(sides="b", position="jitter", colour="blue")
```

But I'm given an error message:

> stat_bin: binwidth defaulted to range/30. Use 'binwidth = x' to adjust this.
>   Error: position_jitter requires the following missing aesthetics: y

The `y` coordinate for a histogram is the count, which the histogram should make automagically.

How can I get my jitters?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply give a y of 0 in an `aes` call, and it will plot everything ok:

```
p + geom_rug(sides = "b", aes(y = 0), position = "jitter", colour = "blue")
```

using some more obvious data:

```
dat <- c(rep(1, 50), rep(2, 50))
dat <- data.frame(dat)
```

without jitter:

[image]

With jitter:

[image]